# Using ACS with Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, single-sign-on, acs

I'm lost. I'm developing a Windows Phone 7 app and I want to do the following:

I want to use Facebook, Live ID, Google and Yahoo to let user sign in my app. And also, it they don't have any of those account I will need to implement a sign up interface on Windows Azure.

I also need to store some ID from user signed in my app. For example, Facebook returns an ID for that user. But Google, Live ID and Yahoo! returns another ID. I will store this on a user table with these columns:

```
ID | Sing-IN-Type | ID-returned
```

**ID**: Primarty Key.

**Sing-IN-Type**: Foreign key to a table with Facebook, Google, etc. names.

**ID-returned**: ID returned by those webs.

I've read about ACS v2 and I'm not sure it will fit with my requisites.  What do you think?

Answer (score 2):

The ACS team has posted a sample that demonstrates how to implement federated auth in a phone app using the silverlight browser control:

http://acs.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=ACS%20Windows%20Phone%20Sample&referringTitle=Samples

The sample doesn't parse the token to extract the claims you're after, but it wouldn't take much code to do it.

After logging in, the application caches the token returned from ACS in a RequestSecurityTresponseStore, which is a member of the MainPage. There are Simple Web Token (SWT) handlers included in the DPE.OAuth project that you can make use of. In the context of MainPage.xaml.cs, the code would look like this:

```
SimpleWebToken swt = (SimpleWebToken)SimpleWebTokenHandler.GetTokenFromString( _rstrStore.SecurityToken );
```

You should then find the IdentityProvider (sign in type) and NameIdentifier (user ID) claims that ACS issued inside the swt.Parameters.

If you want to host your own custom sign in page in this scenario, ACS provides functionality for that as well:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg185963.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could also look at the [hands on labs](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vbertocci/archive/2011/04/13/the-new-hands-on-lab-on-acs-wp7-oauth2-0-odata-service.aspx) from the identity framework.